# Delay-load DLL in windows: can I dynamically choose what DLL name to look for? (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, load, delay

I have a library that calls functions from foo.dll.

In my MSVS settings, I delay load foo.dll and manually check for its existence before attempting to call its functions (so that if it doesn't exist on a machine, my library won't crash).

If the DLL-existence check succeeds and I call its functions, the DLL is auto-loaded by the windows delay load helper and everything functions well.

However, on 50% of my user's machines, foo.dll was renamed to bar.dll. Even if I call LoadLibrary("path\bar.dll") and it succeeds, my library still crashes because the delay load helper still tries to load foo.dll when I call one of the functions.

I used a hex editor to view the content of my library, and in one location "foo.dll" is explicitly named. If I rename that entry to "bar.dll" using the hex editor, my library runs flawless when bar.dll is the name of the DLL on a user's machine (and crashes where foo.dll is the name). So it seems the issue is soley the delay load helper trying to load the explicitly-named DLL inside my library.

How can I tell the delay load helper that the DLL in question goes by a name that doesn't match the explicit file name in my compiled library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell the delay load helper to use a different DLL than what is linked to, you can use a [delay load failure hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/failure-hooks?view=vs-2019). Per MSDN:

[Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs: Error Handling and Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=vs-2019)

> If your code needs to recover **or provide an alternate library** and/or routine on failure, a hook can be provided to the helper function that can supply or remedy the situation. **The hook routine needs to return a suitable value, so that processing can continue** (an HINSTANCE or FARPROC) or 0 to indicate that an exception should be thrown. It could also throw its own exception or longjmp out of the hook. There are notification hooks and failure hooks.

When a delay-loaded DLL fails to load, the hook is called with a `dliFailLoadLib` notification containing details about the load operation and error. The hook can recover from the error by returning a valid `HMODULE` for the helper to use, or return 0 to fail the load operation.

> If the notification is dliFailLoadLib, the hook function can return:
>
> - 0, if it cannot handle the failure.
> - **An HMODULE, if the failure hook fixed the problem and loaded the library itself.**

So, if the error reports the failed DLL is `foo.dll`, your hook can load and return the `HMODULE` for `bar.dll`, and then the helper will load all of `foo.dll`'s delay-loaded functions from `bar.dll` instead.